# CTabView how to prevent switching

Tags: mfc

I use CTabView thats hold different FormViews.
I can switch to another view without any problem.
From a ParamView I don't want to allow switch to another view until the changed value are confirmed.
I have tried it with OnActivateView(..),  OnShowWindow(..). But they are too late, the view are already moved to a another view, then these handlers are fired. :(

```
void CParamView::OnActivateView(BOOL bActivate, CView* pActivateView, CView* pDeactiveView)
{
/*  // did not work, next View already shown before
    if (!bActivate && pActivateView != pDeactiveView)
    {
        if (ParamValueChanged())
        {
            if (!ConfirmChangedValues())
                return;
        }
    }
*/
    CFormView::OnActivateView(bActivate, pActivateView, pDeactiveView);

}
```

Comment: Can we see your implementation of `OnActivateView`? Is it possible for you to use [PreTranslateMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkbhxcs2.aspx)?

Comment: I have learned if you think to use PreTranslateMessage, you are ~90% on the wrong way.

Comment: I think that is a rather unfair % IMHO.